# Spring Security - avoiding in-web-container role binding removes flexibility

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, web.xml, user-roles, open-liberty

If using Spring Security in-app authentication/authorization, I would like the flexibility I have when I use J2EE **web.xml** descriptor and in-web-container authentication/authorization.

I am using LDAP (Active Directory as IP, **not DAO**).

I understand Spring Boot has moved from use of **web.xml** descriptor but I have a situation like this and I wonder if there is a workaround in Spring Boot.

Currently, most of our apps are using J2EE and in-container authentication/authorization mechanism (web containers like OpenLiberty, Jetty or similar). We are switching
to Spring Boot and would prefer using in-app Spring Security authentication/authorization.

But I do have one concern.

Organizations can have number of different environments they deploy applications for testing, staging, until the production. Let's say an organization has btw 5-10 environments.

Typically, if I would start with a new app, I would follow these steps:

1. use **web.xml** descriptor to define , say I define **ROLE-A, ROLE-B, ROLE-C** in **web.xml** of my app.
2. once ready, hand in my application to infrastructure teams responsible for deployments to ENV1, ENV2, ENV3, ENV4, ENV5, ...
3. infrastructure team would open **web.xml** and see defining **ROLE-A, ROLE-B,** and **ROLE-C**
4. from here, they would define and externalize users and goups (so they can be resolved using ${...}) having certain roles in **server.env** file.  For example

   GROUP-A_DEVS=devs_group1
   ROLE-A_USER1=bob
   ROLE-A_USER2=mike
   GROUP-B_DEVS=devs_group2
   ROLE-B_USER1=bob
5. from here, infrastructure team would create **server.xml** file with section in which they would bind roles to users or groups.  So, for **ENV1**, they could do something like:

```
<application-bnd>
 <security-role name="ROLE-A">
     <group name="${GROUP-A_DEVS}" />
     <user name="${ROLE-A_USER1}" />
     <user name="${ROLE-A_USER2}" />
 </security-role>
 <security-role name="ROLE-B">
     <group name="${GROUP-A_DEVS}" />
     <group name="${GROUP-B_DEVS}" />
    <user name="${ROLE-A_USER1}"/>
 </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

From above, they defined that

- Externalized **GROUP-A** , **user1** and **user2** are mapped to **ROLE-A**, and
- Externalized **GROUP-A**, **GROUP-B**, and **user1** and mapped to **ROLE-B** in **ENV1**.

But we have multiple environments and they have different mappings. For example **ENV1** has mapping like above.  Infrastructure team can now go and add new environment **ENV2** or modify it if it existed as they see fit without involving developer at all.

So, they can create **ENV2** mapping like:

- in **server.env** for **ENV2** add

  ROLE-B_USER3=carl
- in **server.xml** for **ENV2**, add:

```
<application-bnd>
     <security-role name="ROLE-B">
        <user name="${ROLE-B_USER3}"/>
     </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

, where **user3** is mapped to **ROLE-B**. This shows why this is very flexible. It is because now, infrastructure team can add all these users to the **server.env** file so:

- for **ENV1**, **server.env** would have something like:

  ROLE-A_USER1=user1

  ROLE-A_USER2=user2

  ROLE-B_USER1=user1
- for **ENV2**, **server.env** would have something like:

  ROLE-B_USER3=user3

etc, to externalize them to **server.env** file, **THEN MAP THEM** in **server.xml** file which is also in their ownership and control.  Both of these files are owned by infrastructure (in fact, they are the only ones who might have access to these).  Developers can independently create their own local versions and map them how ever they wish

This shows how infrastructure/security teams can control which users are assigned to which roles and they can also add them or remove them.  The only time app needs to be changed is if a NEW role is added, for example **ROLE-X**, in which case, that role would have to be added to app **web.xml**.  But that is all.

Obviously, roles once added change less often than users that belong to these roles and that is handled entirely by security or infrastructure teams, no development knowledge required.  Devs can setup their own local instance of web-container however they want to do their work.

The above shows the flexibility of **web.xml** and in-web-container role mapping. I, as developer, define roles in the app **web.xml** file and hand that to infrastructure. And they
can define mapping in the web-container **server.xml** section how to map these roles per each environment without my knowledge.

With Spring-Boot and in-app Spring Security handling authentication/authorization, I dont think this is possible.

I know Spring Boot uses **application.properties**. Perhaps I could define app roles there instead of **web.xml**. However, I see no way to map these roles
to the groups and users defined in the section in **server.xml**.

Curently, I do it like this in my Spring Boot app

- in web-container **server.env**, I have defined variables like:

  ROLE-A_USER1=joe

  ROLE-A_USER2=mike

  ROLE-B_USER1=kevin
- in Spring Boot **application.properties**, I parameterize these to get them from **server.env** at run-time:

  role.a.user1=${ROLE-A_USER1}

  role.a.user2=${ROLE-A_USER2}

  role.b.user1=${ROLE-B_USER1}
- then in app, I get these from environment like:

  environment.getProperty("role.a.user1")

But as you can see this is very impractical.

1. First flexibility is lost as I have to know in advance **all** settings on **all** environments's **server.env** files in
   order to code them in my **application.properties** then in my code get them using `enviroment.getProperty()` or `@Value` annotation or however.
2. Second, I have to code them **all** in my application code so I can get them.
3. Third, if infrastructure team might tomorrow decide to add a new user **ROLE-X_USER5=bob**, I have to modify the code or that user will never be accounted for.
4. Fourth, if infrastructure names a variable differently than I did, I need to know that exact name in order to parameterize it in my **application.properties**, else I will not be able to get it

I know that in Spring Boot, I could use `jee.mappableRoles(...)` to pass the roles defined in the app to the web-container so it can map them to the mappings defined in **server.xml** `<application-bnd>` section.
But this would be using J2EE in-container authorization role mapping.

I wonder if there is a way to do that without involvement of J2EE and to do it entirely from within the application.  This is in order to make my app
web container agnostic and to use entirely Spring Security in-app authentication/authorization as we find that that removes silos mentality btw 2
teams (developers and infrastructure) and gives better understanding and easier handling of issues if something goes wrong as developer has full
knowledge and ability to do modifications.

Comment: Just some thoughts, no answer: 1. I didn't see any container deployment (with Spring Boot) in a real prject ever. 2. Roles are defined by dev teams, not infrastructure teams. If you add a role, you have to change the app. 3. `web.xml` is just one way to communicate the roles, you could do it also with a readme file. 4. In my projects the mapping between users and roles were in LDAP, not in the container.

Comment: hi and thank you for your reply.  I have to disagree with 1 totally.  With 4 partially as both are possible however this question is about mapping users and roles in web-container (check about <application-bnd>).  Re 2, I agree and that is what I said, dev writes web.xml with role defininitions, then infrastructure takes it from there.  I know my question is long but please check again.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize (correct me if anything is wrong), you are working with the following concepts and attempting to build a replacement using only Spring Security's authorization concepts:

1. A way to communicate roles to an infrastructure team (equivalent to list of role names in `web.xml`)
2. A way to define mappings between roles and a list of users, list of groups, or both (equivalent to mappings in `server.xml`)
3. A means of specifying the actual runtime values of these mappings using environment variables (?)

**#1:** As mentioned in comments, communicating the roles is simply documentation because the container doesn't need to know about roles ahead of time. We develop the application to use roles however we wish (request-level authorization rules, `@PreAuthorize`, etc.), and simply document that in whatever way makes the most sense. For example, we could provide a sample properties file as an example, document it in a readme, etc.

**#2:** Defining mappings between users and roles requires populating a list of authorities when the user logs in. How this would work is entirely up to you. For example, we could define Spring Boot application properties to do the mapping, and create a `UserDetailsService` that applies the mappings.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("application.security")
public class ApplicationSecurityProperties {

    private Map<String, Role> roles = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // getters and setters...

    public static class Role {

        private List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();

        private List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

        // getters and setters...

    }

}
```

For testing, we could define an `application-dev.yml` (or properties) which enables the use of a `dev` profile:

```yaml
application:
  security:
    roles:
      ROLE_A:
        groups:
          - GROUP_A
        users:
          - user1
          - user2
      ROLE_B:
        groups:
          - GROUP_A
          - GROUP_B
        users:
          - user1
```

**Note:** I used underscores instead of dashes for consistency with Spring Security default of `ROLE_` prefix.

The infrastructure team can define their own files with profiles for `env1`, `env2`, etc.

How we apply these mappings to authorities depends on what type of authentication is being performed, but I'll just provide an example using the in-memory `UserDetailsService`, with groups provided as authorities (for example purposes):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/role-a").hasRole("A")
                .requestMatchers("/role-b").hasRole("B")
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(ApplicationSecurityProperties applicationSecurityProperties) {
        UserDetailsService delegate = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users());
        return (username) -> {
            UserDetails user = delegate.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Set<String> groups = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(user.getAuthorities());

            List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            applicationSecurityProperties.getRoles().forEach((roleName, role) -> {
                boolean hasMatchingUser = role.getUsers().contains(user.getUsername());
                boolean hasMatchingGroup = role.getGroups().stream().anyMatch(groups::contains);
                if (hasMatchingUser || hasMatchingGroup) {
                    authorities.add(roleName);
                }
            });

            return User.withUserDetails(user)
                .authorities(AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authorities))
                .build();
        };
    }

    private static List<UserDetails> users() {
        User.UserBuilder builder = User.builder().password("{noop}password");
        UserDetails user1 = builder.username("user1").build();
        UserDetails user2 = builder.username("user2").build();
        UserDetails user3 = builder.username("user3").authorities("GROUP_A").build();
        UserDetails user4 = builder.username("user4").authorities("GROUP_B").build();
        UserDetails user5 = builder.username("user5").authorities("GROUP_A", "GROUP_B").build();
        UserDetails user6 = builder.username("user6").authorities("GROUP_C").build();

        return Arrays.asList(user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6);
    }

}
```

**#3:** The solution above is simple and fairly flexible, so I'm not sure there's a need for another level of abstraction to perform the mappings. However, if you want to use environment variables to define the actual usernames, group names, or whatever, Spring Boot provides many ways of [externalizing the configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) and [binding properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding).

For example, the above properties could instead use environment variables like this:

```yaml
application:
  security:
    roles:
      ROLE_A:
        groups:
          - GROUP_A
        users:
          - ${ROLE_A_USER1}
          - ${ROLE_A_USER2}
      ROLE_B:
        groups:
          - GROUP_A
          - GROUP_B
        users:
          - ${ROLE_B_USER1}
```

But again, this doesn't seem necessary since the environment-specific application properties could be provided and activated via a profile controlled by infrastructure team. There's no need to further externalize what's already externalized.

Comment: Thank you @Steve.  I updated the original SO to reflect that we do externalize the users already.  Also, I explain how we do it in-container, and now in Spring Security (without container and `jee().mappableRoles` to pass them to the container.  So, I do have solution for 1, 2, and 3 you explained above already.  What I am saying is that it is not practical since devs need to have prior knowledge of what is in server.env files for each environment.  Please my SO above and the last 4 points I explained why it is not practical.  That is what I am trying to make better.  Much appreciated ...

Comment: ... the inflexibility I am explaining is also visible in your points 2 and 3.   For example in your application-envX.yaml you use externalized ${ROLE_A_USER1}.  That exactly is the probem.  You MUST know EXACTLY what that variable is called (ROLE_A_USER1) and MUST know exactly in which environment in order to be able to locate it in server settings files.  Exactly my point, devs and infrastructure MUST agree on exact naming and each time new user is added or ANY env, they MUST agree, it MUST be called ROLE_X_USER_X; otherwise in-app spring security WILL NOT BE ABLE to resolve that variable.

Comment: "Please my SO above and the last 4 points I explained why it is not practical. That is what I am trying to make better." Sorry, I don't follow what you're asking for in this comment. My answer is not similar to your solution, which seems to be using `@Value` to inject specific variables into a security config. My example solution allows a configurable number of users to be added, without the developer needing to know or change anything at the application level. I think you're confused by who owns `application-env1.yml`, it is the infrastructure team that can provide this.

Comment: I meant, please see my question and search for string "But as you can see this is very impractical.", then the 4 points below that.  Also, application-evnX.yml is owned by devs, it is part of the app.  Server settings files (server.env, server.xml) however are owned by infrastructure.  In your solution, as I mentioned above example of ROLE_A_USER1 - the exact naming MUST be known in advance and agreed btw devs and infrastructure - since devs are resolving its external references in application-evnX.yml.  My comment exactly before your last reply explains it nicely....

Comment: So, the 4 points I refer to attempted to explain issue but actually your point 2 and 3 demonstrate it clearly.  The issue is not externalizing (sorry if that confused you).  The issue is that exact spellings and variables like "ROLE_A_USER1" MUST BE KNOWN by dev, since devs need to get that EXACT externalized name (from infrastructure setting files) in their application-envX.yml file or in their code in order to be able to use it.  Say infrastructure decides to add new env ENVX and map different users/groups to existing roles - they MUST communicate EXACT spelling to devs

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that I'm misunderstanding you. I do think we're not on the same page about our assumptions. I'm proposing that `application-envX.yml` is *not* defined by developers, but in fact defined by the infrastructure team in an externalized configuration. I'm not clear on why you insist that this file must be owned by developers, but that is clearly the point of debate. If you read the Spring Boot docs, you will see that this file can be provided externally. To be clear, `application-<profile>.yml` is equivalent to `server.xml`.

Comment: I feel same, hence asking :).  Thank you.  I'd like to understand how that works because that might solve the issue for me.  The reason I say `app-envX.yml` is owned by devs is that that file is part of the project folders structure (*app/src/main/resources/application.properties*).  From what you are saying, looks like `application.properties` could be provided somewhere else.  My problem with that is that there are many settings in this file developer needs to set.  Only the role/user mapping is what infrastructure needs to set.  Could you provide some links about this?  Much appreciated

Comment: I provided links in my answer to the Spring Boot docs. I'd encourage you to read that, as indeed there are many more ways of providing application properties. What I'm suggesting is that you allow your infrastructure team to provide an environment-specific file with *only* the users/groups mapping. Other settings can be provided by the developer in the jar. Spring Boot will combine all properties sources (including profile-based properties) into a single configuration, with precedence based rules (overrides) as outlined in the docs. Please read the docs for details.

Comment: Much appreciated Steve.  I will go through that.  I know Spring merges properties files and I know they can be even externalized to some other location (not just project folder structure) but I forgot about that and never saw an example explaining how to do that.  For example how to make it include that externalized properties file from some location and still merge it into property files you have in your project.  I will definitelly read.  Much appreciated

Comment: I have to say after reading the 2 ursl you provided, all I got out of it is that it is possible but I am still not sure how.  I will google bit more but I just wanted to confirm with you.   But just to confirm, what you are saying is ...

Comment: ... What you are saying is (1) have in application resources folder your regular application.properties file with your settings, (2) let infrastructure team create their own application.properties file with security roles/users mapping per each environment (so instead of server.xml <application-bnd>, just have these in application-env1.properties etc, (3) have Spring Boot app merge these two.  Is that what youo meant and my question is if yes, how is (3) done?  Thanks again

Comment: Yes. Please ask a new question on SO.

Comment: I finally had time to get back to this and figured it finally out thanks to you Steve.  Much appreciated